# Codeigniter caching web-page vs database. What is the Deference?

Tags: php, codeigniter, caching, frameworks, database-caching

Now I just starting using codeigniter as framework.
I have a lot of data will be saved on database.
I read more on caching system of codeigniter. And I found that there is two types of caching on it DATABASE CACHING & WEB PAGE CACHING.
My Question here is, When must I use database caching ? And when must I use web-page caching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me put a quote from [the docs](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/caching.html),

> Unfortunately there is no single answer to the question of whether you should cache your database. It really depends on your situation.

That also aligns with my suggestion to you. Look at both, Database Caching and Web Page Caching as two mechanisms on your disposal when there's a **specific performance problem to solve**. Then consider them both, how they fit in and base your pick on that.